# matplotlib mathtext \frac is too small

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

When I give matplotlib a annotation string such as

```
'$\frac{A}{B} = C$'
```

and I specify a fontsize of 18, the A and B are rendered at 12.6 pt, while the C is rendered at 18 pt.  I want A, B, and C to all be the same size.  How do I do this?

In a LaTeX document, if you give the commands

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{A}{B} = C
\end{equation}
```

you get a fraction, where A, B, and C are all the same size, but if you do

```
$\frac{A}{B} = C$
```

inline with text, you get the A and B rendered at 12.6 pt, while the C is rendered at 18 pt.  Thus it appears matplotlib's mathtext is emulating LaTeX's inline mode.  In LaTeX you can write

```
$\displaystyle\frac{A}{B} = C$
```

and then A, B, and C are all the same size, even in inline mode.  I tried this in matplotlib, but mathtext did not recognize the command \displaystyle.  =(

Is there a way to get this to work in Matplotlib's mathtext, or am I stuck changing text.usetex to true in my .matplotlibrc file?  (If possible I would like to stay with mathtext since it is a lot faster.)

My setup:
matplotlib v1.2.0
python 2.7
OS X 10.8

Comment: Perhaps see if some ideas in [Setting math font size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94232/5764) solves your problem.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the link, but I did not find anything that worked.  The \Large, \Huge, \small, etc commands only work for text or equation mode.  They do not work in inline math mode ($ ... $), which is the only mode for mathtext.  The rest of the discussion in the link seems to pertain only to Matlab.  Perhaps I just need to ask the matplotlib developers if they can implement \displaystyle into mathtext.

Comment: Do that, report back and share with the community.

Comment: @Werner: Ok.  I submitted a feature request at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1888

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this and also not wanting to set `"text.usetex"` to `True`, matplotlib [now supports](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/8151) the `\dfrac` macro (equivalent to `\displaystyle\frac` in LaTeX) to replace `\frac` since version 2.1

Comment: That's awesome news.  The funny thing is I am friends with the guy who implemented \dfrac, yet I did not know he did it.

Answer (score 4):

As you said, you can fix it by using \displaystyle:

```
$\displaystyle\frac{A}{B} = C$
```

In order to allow matplotlib to use latex for all text handling you have to define in your matplotlibrc the text.usetex variable as True:

```
text.usetex          : True
```

I made a little example to verify it and it is working well:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(200))
plt.text(100,50,r'$\displaystyle\frac{A}{B}=C$')
```

I am sorry but since I am new, I can not post any image.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  As I mention at the bottom of my post, I would rather not use latex for all text handling.  It is quite slow.  I want to use mathtext.